# MySQL Nested Select Querys using data from main query

Tags: mysql, nested

**I have edited the question to make the problem more simple and added the suggested changes in the coments, Thx a lot**

I have a table matches with data and I need:

1- To get all the columns for matches before a date.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4ff02f/18

```
SELECT m1.* FROM matches AS m1 WHERE m1.date < '2019-02-23 00:00:00'
```

2- I need to add two columns with the “streak” for home and away teams in each match (or row). The “streak” for a team is the count of matches before the date of the current match in same competition, until the team lost a game (being home or away indistintly). The result would be kind of this:

[results desired](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AtENL.png)

[image]

I need to get all the info in only one query in MySql…and I am getting crazy with JOINS, SUBQUERIES,….They don´t get to do what I mean. Really appreciate some help
Thanks!

Comment: Screenshots are not safe. Provide CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO scripts. And show desired result.

Comment: Thanks for the comments! I already add the info the best I could since I lack the query for the result desired. I hope it helps

Comment: Please post the content of the SQLFIDDLE here in addition to putting it on SQLFIDDLE. Normally it's a Polite Practice to include the entire question on this site rather than have an external requirement to read the entire question. Also including a link to SQLFIDDLE is a nice "addon".

Comment: Added!, I am new so I appreciate the advice

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to only populate specific fields for your streaks and that you want cumulative data. You may need to use fields that don't show (invisible, or just at the end) for "win/lose" and cumulative data to provide the count.

I don't have time to write a full solution right now, but this will be too long for a "comment" so bear with me:

1. Add columns for "Win" in home and away. Place a 1 or 0 accordingly.
2. Add columns for streak and conditionally include a cumulative count of Win IF the Win is 1. But if the win is Zero, set the cumulative back to Zero.

Example of CASE: https://www.w3schools.com/mysql/func_mysql_case.asp

Example of Cumulative: https://popsql.com/learn-sql/mysql/how-to-calculate-cumulative-sum-running-total-in-mysql

Once you have it written, you could likely combine these into a single function/field. But ... baby steps. Like the rest of us. :)

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I thought of something similar but I discarded it because if any match updates I should check and update the streaks for other columns. Anyway if I do not find a way to do it "on the fly" I will reconsider it